# How do I correctly loop; Draw open line and stop drawing once it is hit?

Tags: mql4

I am having trouble finding/understanding the correct logic.

The Indicator is supposed to check X bars back, draw open line of a valid candle (i.e twice the size of the prev.), and when price crosses the line, it should change color (and stop drawing at the time it was touched)

The first part / first loop (finding the candle and drawing the line) is working correctly so far. However I am lost figuring out how/where to loop the second part (check if price crossed the line, and change color and/or stop drawing the line)

- Do I do everything in one loop or do I need to use two loops?
- If two loops, must they be separate or nested?
- During a 2nd Loop: Should I get the price of the open line by iOpen, or get the price from the line using GetObject?

Any help or pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.
Also, please excuse my mediocre English, as it is not my native language.

Thanks

Edit: I need several lines, one from every valid candle. This is the code I have so far:

```
  #property indicator_chart_window
  #property indicator_buffers         2
  #property indicator_color1          Green
  #property indicator_color2          Red

  extern bool    DrawArrows           = true;
  extern int     TimeFrame            = 0;
  extern double  CandleFactor         = 1.8 ; // Min Candle Factor
  extern double  CandleMinPip         = 20 ; // Min Pips to show Candle (in pts)
  extern int     CountBars            = 24;
  extern color   LinecolorL           = Green;
  extern color   LinecolorS           = Red;
  extern color   LinecolorHit         = Blue;
  extern int     Width                = 2;
  extern int     ShiftLineRightBars   = 6 ;

  double Up[], Down[], EntryPriceArray[], OpenPriceArray[];
  double close2, open2, close1, open1, pips1, pips2, EntryPrice, OpenPrice;
  string can2, can1, label, period;
  int i;
  color Linecolor;
  static bool CrossedLine = false;
  //+------------------------------------------------------------------+

  int init()
    {
     SetIndexBuffer(0,Up);
     SetIndexBuffer(1,Down);
     if(DrawArrows){SetIndexStyle(0,DRAW_ARROW);}else{SetIndexStyle(0,DRAW_NONE);}
     if(DrawArrows){SetIndexStyle(1,DRAW_ARROW);}else{SetIndexStyle(1,DRAW_NONE);}
     SetIndexArrow(0,233);
     SetIndexArrow(1,234);

     CandleMinPip = CandleMinPip*Point;

     if (Period() == 1){period = "M1"; Width = 1; ShiftLineRightBars = ShiftLineRightBars + 5;}
     if (Period() == 5){period = "M5"; Width = 2; ShiftLineRightBars = ShiftLineRightBars + 3;}
     if (Period() == 15){period = "M15"; Width = 2; ShiftLineRightBars = ShiftLineRightBars + 2;}
     if (Period() == 30){period = "M30"; Width = 3;}
     if (Period() == 60){period = "H1"; Width = 3;}
     if (Period() == 240){period = "H4"; Width = 4;}
     if (Period() == 1440){period = "D1"; Width = 5;}

     return(0);
    }
  //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
  int deinit()
    { if (CountBars == 0) {CountBars=Bars;}
      for( i = 0; i < CountBars; i++) {
      ObjectDelete("Line_"+period+"_"+Time[i+1]);
    }
     return(0);
    }
  //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
  int start() {
     if (CountBars == 0) {CountBars=Bars;}
     for( i = 0; i < CountBars; i++){

        close1=iClose(NULL,TimeFrame,i+1);
        close2=iClose(NULL,TimeFrame,i+2);
        open1=iOpen(NULL,TimeFrame,i+1);
        open2=iOpen(NULL,TimeFrame,i+2);
        pips1 = (MathAbs(open1-close1));
        pips2 = (MathAbs(open2-close2));

              if ( pips1 > CandleMinPip){
               if ( pips1 > pips2*CandleFactor){
                int CandleTime = Time[i+1];                  // Get the Candle time of Candle i+1
                // int CandleTimeClose = CandleTime+(Period()*60*ShiftLineRightBars);
                int CandleTimeClose = Time[0];
                label = "Line_"+period+"_"+Time[i+1];

                  if (open1-close1 < 0){                   // Candle 1 is Bullish
                  Up[i+1]=iLow(NULL,TimeFrame,i+1);
                  EntryPrice = iHigh(NULL,TimeFrame,i+1);
                  Linecolor = LinecolorL;
                  }

                  if (open1-close1 > 0){                   // Candle 1 is Bearish
                  Down[i+1]=iHigh(NULL,TimeFrame,i+1);
                  EntryPrice = iLow(NULL,TimeFrame,i+1);
                  Linecolor = LinecolorS;
                  }

                  OpenPrice = iOpen(NULL,TimeFrame,i+1);  // Open Price of BiggerCandle

                  ObjectCreate(label, OBJ_TREND, 0, CandleTime, OpenPrice, CandleTimeClose, OpenPrice, 0, 0);
                  ObjectSet(label, OBJPROP_RAY, 0);
                  ObjectSet(label, OBJPROP_COLOR, Linecolor);
                  ObjectSet(label, OBJPROP_WIDTH, Width);
                  ObjectSet(label, OBJPROP_STYLE, 0);

                } // End CandleFactor  
               } // End CandleMinPip

                    if (open1-close1 > 0 &&  Bid > OpenPrice && CrossedLine == false) {   // If Bid crosses/is above the OpenPrice, Change Line Color and Change CandleTimeClose
                    ObjectSet(label, OBJPROP_COLOR, LinecolorHit);
                    CrossedLine = true;
                    //CandleTimeClose = TimeCurrent();
                    //ObjectSet(label, OBJPROP_TIME2, CandleTimeClose);
                    }

                    if (open1-close1 < 0 &&  Bid < OpenPrice && CrossedLine == false) {   // If Bid crosses/is below the OpenPrice, Change Line Color and Change CandleTimeClose
                    ObjectSet(label, OBJPROP_COLOR, LinecolorHit);
                    CrossedLine = true;
                    //CandleTimeClose = TimeCurrent();
                    //ObjectSet(label, OBJPROP_TIME2, CandleTimeClose);
                    }
     } // End "i"                
     return(0);
  }
```

Comment: if you need only one line (only x bars back from the current candle) - another loop. if you need to find a level for many candles, not only the last one - more complex logic is needed, example of the code you have and the logic you wish to implement

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have edited the opening post to include the code.
I need several lines, one for each valid candle.

Comment: I would suggest creating some kind of structures or classes that has the line, direction (above or below) and time when it started to draw. once you draw a line, add such structure into an array or CArrayObj. then check all the array in order to make sure the lines are valid or that you have to change its color (and remove the line from the array)